# fallbackType:fallback and translations in freemode in TYPO3 11

Tags: typo3

I am confronted with the following problem:

Site definition in a TYPO3 11 LTS installation: fallbacktype:fallback

- translations of content elements in connected mode are shown in the frontend
- translations of content elements in free mode are NOT shown in the frontend

site definition in a TYPO3 11 LTS installation fallbacktype:free

- translations of content elements in connected mode are NOT shown in the frontend
- translations of content elements in free mode are shown in the frontend

What is wrong here? Of course the editors use both modes depending on their needs ... How can I get both translation modes visible in the frontend?

Thanks

Comment: is the content coming from extbase plugins? then the extension https://github.com/georgringer/extbase_with_no_l10n_parent could help

Comment: No, every content element from TYPO3.

Comment: Actually I doubt that both modes can be mixed, as they are defined for a language on site level. So you had to find a special solution for your purpose.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, David! But i do have difficulties with understandig the usabilty behind it. How do you explain your editors that they must not use free mode when they translate content because you defined the fallbacktype fallback in the site definition? They see both modes every time when they translate content on the page. In my opinion both modes have to work therefore.

Comment: I tried both combination in a fresh installation of the introduction package and it works as expected: both modes are visible in the translation regardless of the site definition. So TYPO3 works as expected and there has to be an error in my client installation (which i took from an other developer ...). Thats actually good news :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is expected behaviour, because fallbackType "fallback" first loads all contents from default language and then overlays them with translations. So contents without a connection to a default language record are not respected here. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AddLanguages.html#fallbacktype

Your second example could be a bug, since there are many open issues on forge related to language modes. Example: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86627

If you find your problem on forge please add a commend there to get more attention to the issue.

Comment: Thanks Tobias for your answer. But i dont understand most of it. Both described methods worked up to version 10 of TYPO3, so i dont think it is an old bug. And they should work both because both methods are presented to the editors after clicking the button "Translate" regardless what fallback type is defined in the site definition. It would be an impossible situation if an editor must not use free mode when fallback is defined in the site definition or connected mode when fallbacktype free is defined.

Comment: The (understanding) problem is that the fallbackType just hadles the fallback behaviour for contents in the frontent. Backend translation strategie is independent from that. That of cause causes a lot of confusion, see: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88966

Comment: I read your issue on forge and would agree. But it deals with TYPO3 9 and perhaps 10 and TYPO3 11 behaves somewhat different. In my opinion the backend and the frontend differs now i a way that the usability is completely broken. If in the site the fallbacktype is strict or fallback you cannot use free mode or mixed mode at all because you wont get any single content element in the frontend. Even the introduction package is broken, it shows in free mode both: the default + the translated content.

Comment: Then please create a new issue on forge for that - if related link it to some already existing ones.